# How to upload/insert binary (blob) data to Cassandra 2.2 database (using DevCenter or cqlsh)

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

Hi I'm new to Cassandra/CQL but have SQL/relational database experience.

I have a very simple key space and table setup for testing purposes and need to add some very basic data - some of which is in BLOB format.

```
CREATE TABLE file_share (
   key varchar,
   content_type varchar,
   client_id varchar,
   org_id varchar,
   user_id varchar,
   value blob,
   internal_key uuid,
   PRIMARY KEY (client_id, org_id, user_id, key)
);
```

The trouble for me right now is:  How can i (using a script INSERT statement or the like) put some dummy data - specifically in the blob itself so that I can use it for testing?  Is there a way to upload a file?  If so, how?  If not, is there a better way to get binary data as blob?  I've been trying to find a list of blob handling functions for CQL but can't find anything so far.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just for testing you can use the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO file_share (client_id, org_id, user_id, key, value)
       VALUES ('A', 'B', 'C' , 'D', 0xabcd);
```

I don't know of any way to input file data to a blob using cqlsh.